# Ryanair have cancelled an outward flight. Can I claim the cost of the return flight?

Tags: cancellations, compensation, ryanair

Ryanair have cancelled an outward flight. Can I claim the cost of the return flight from them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you asking if you can get the inbound flight refunded? Is the inbound flight also booked with Ryanair?

Comment: Could you tell us more? How much in advance they cancelled the outward flight? Do you have a single booking? (a single reference number)

Comment: @Kate J What options did Ryanair offer you for the cancelled flight? https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/disruptions-and-refunds/disruptions/flight-cancellations Do you mean you don’t want to make the trip at all?

Answer (score 3):

I am writing this totally on the base of my experience with Ryan Air, a couple of year ago.

1. If you have purchased your ticket from the official Ryan Air site then Yes. Retrieve your booking and ask for a refund. 
   https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/check-in
   Note: If they call you then be confident and ask only for refund mentioning you get such kind of services from other airlines too.
2. Forget about a refund if you have use the third party to book the ticket.
3. You should ask for a refund soon else you will face delay on handling your issue.

Comment: Why should you forget about a refund if you used a third party?